# How do I pass a populated c structure to python (without ctypes)

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-embedding, pyobject

How can I pass a c structure to python without using ctypes ?

I have a pointer to a `stats_res_t` structure that I'm trying to return to python.

I'm trying something along the lines of

```
PyObject* pyobject_get_system_stats(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *temp;

    PyObject *resultlist;
    PyObject *res;
    stats_res_t *response;

    if(PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"O",&temp))
    {

        resultlist=PyDict_Values(temp);
        res=PyList_AsTuple(resultlist);

        // populate response

    }
    return Py_BuildValue("O",response);
}
```

but it causes segfault in python.

Is it possible to pass a populated structure to python using `PyObject` ?

Comment: I'm no `PyObject` expert but probably giving `stats_res_t` definition might help too